# How can I update a SQL Server Project in Visual Studio 2013 if the deployed database is changed from another source?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools

I have a SQL Server Project in Visual Studio 2013. I created it by importing the database from a preexisting db. We have other devs who may have made changes to the database using ssms or some other means. How can I update my SQL Server project to reflect these changes? Is there a simple way that I'm missing or do I have to modify/add all of the changed tables manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after a ton of googling that didn't yield very good results, I continued to play around with the project and figured out that you can use Visual Studio's schema comparison to update the SQL Server Project.

Go to tools -> SQL Server -> New Schema Comparison
Select the source database as your source.
Select your SQL Server Project as the target.
Run the comparison and update the target from the schema compare.